# атрибут для разделения по строчкам

Tags: android, xml

Есть radiobuttongroup в котором 4 radiobutton. Эти кнопки идут на разметке в ряд. Как сделать так, чтобы 2 кнопки были на одной строке, а другие соответственно на следующей.

```
<com.example.radiobutton.PresetRadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/preset_time_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="397dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >

         <com.example.radiobutton.PresetValueButton
            android:id="@+id/preset_time_value_button_30"
            style="@style/PresetLayoutButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            app:presetButtonValueText="@string/title_time_preset_normal" />

        <com.example.radiobutton.PresetValueButton
            android:id="@+id/preset_time_value_button_60"
            style="@style/PresetLayoutButton"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            app:presetButtonValueText="@string/title_time_preset_fat" />
  

        <com.example.radiobutton.PresetValueButton
            android:id="@+id/preset_time_value_button_120"
            style="@style/PresetLayoutButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            app:presetButtonValueText="@string/title_time_preset_dry" />

        <com.example.radiobutton.PresetValueButton
            android:id="@+id/preset_time_value_button_150"
            style="@style/PresetLayoutButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            app:presetButtonValueText="@string/title_time_preset_combined" />
</com.example.radiobutton.PresetRadioGroup>
```

Comment: источник https://crosp.net/blog/software-development/mobile/android/creating-custom-radio-groups-radio-buttons-android/

Comment: android:orientation="horizontal" изменить к примеру на вертикальную разметку?

Comment: @Yakov кнопки вообще исчезли

Comment: размеры поставь врап контент, а не фиксированные, они у тебя просто в разметку не влезли и их скрыло.

Comment: @Yakov справедливо. теперь они просто в столбик

Comment: стандартной возможности сделать такое нет